# Cannot figure out the google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

Hello I am trying to get the debugkey google maps api key on windows 7 and I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

So i go into the command prompt and paste the directory to where the debug.keystore is. Here is what I have tried

```
C:\Users\Nana>C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore>keytool -list -alias android
debugkey -keystore C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -key
pass android

C:\Users\Nana>C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -ke
ypass android
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\Nana>C:\Users\Nana\.android\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keyst
ore -keypass C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass a
ndroid
'C:\Users\Nana\.android\keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external co
mmand,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Nana>C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore\keytool -list -alias android
debugkey -keystore C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -key
pass android
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\Nana>C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore>keytool -list -alias android
debugkey -keystore C:\Users\Nana\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -key
pass android
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using windows 7 and my all android setup is in C drive. I can get the debug.keystore in my personal folder below are the instruction how can u get it:

press Start->click the right top(personal folder) it may be yiur name->.android.

in .android folder you will get the debug.keystore.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way,

```
keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\HOME\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Comment: Still getting keytool is not recognized